# SharePoint Server 2019 on-premise REST API Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, authentication, c-sharp

I need to read list data from SharePoint 2019 on-premise server, from an external server. I have tried calling the REST API but I am having trouble authenticating.

Things I have tried:

- Calling REST endpoint with Network Credentials:

  ```
   var client = new RestClient(url);
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain") };
   var response = client.Execute(request);
   return response.Content;
  ```

I am getting 403 response in this case.

- I was successful with a cookie I obtained when accessing the site from the browser (this is not a solution):

  ```
   var client = new RestClient(url);
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
   request.AddHeader("Cookie", "cookie-value");
   return response.Content;
  ```

What kind of authentication is needed to perform calls to SharePoint REST API? I have also looked up custom Add-Ins, but can only find documentation for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Wanted to ask if you were able to authenticate with OAUTH 2 or some other mechanism?